# Automatic numbering is now assigning 99 for the year

Tags: workflow-activity, auto-increment

I created an auto-generating number assignment log. The log was working correctly until a few days ago and began assigning **99** for the 2 digit year instead of **18**.

What possibly went wrong? Could my workflow be corrupted?

Comment: Can you share the logic you use?

Comment: I am very new to this and not sure of what you mean by logic.  But here is the formula is used in a calculated column: ="PRO-IS-"&Location&TEXT(Created,"-yy")&CONCATENATE("-",REPT("0",MAX(0,3-LEN(ItemID))),ItemID)

Comment: What about your workflow what does that do?

Comment: Hello, thanks for responding to me.  I was able to find the issue.

Answer (score 0):

When I set the condition of "If any value equals value" where the Value Project Number equals....., I did not complete it with "List Lookup" and the source of the Lookup.

Therefore, the workflow threw the error.